# Importing RedisTimeSeries data into Grafana

Tags: redis, grafana

I've got a process storing RedisTimeSeries data in a Redis instance on Docker. I can access the data just fine with the RedisInsight CLI: [image]

I can also add Redis as a data source to Grafana:
[image]

I've imported the dashboards:

[image]

But when I actually try to import the data into a Grafana dashboard, the query just sits there:

[image]

TS.RANGE with a value of - +, or two timestamps, also produces nothing: [image] (I do get results when entering it into the CLI, but not as a CLI query in Grafana.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked into this a bit more. Moderators deleted my last answer because it didn't 'answer' the question.

There is a github issue for this. One of the developers also responded. It is broken and has been for awhile. Grafana doesn't seem to want to maintain this datasource at the moment. IMHO they should remove the redis timeseries support from their plugin library if it isn't fully baked.

[redis datasource issue for TS.RANGE]
[1]: https://github.com/RedisGrafana/grafana-redis-datasource/issues/254

Answer (score 2):

The command you should be using in the Grafana dashboard for retrieving and visualising the data in time series stored in Redis with RedisTimeSeries is `TS.RANGE` for a specific key, or `TS.MRANGE` in combination with a filter that selects a set of time series matching this filter. List of commands with RedisTimeSeries: https://oss.redislabs.com/redistimeseries/commands/ (you're using TS.INFO which does only retrieve metadata of time series key, not the actual samples within)

Comment: Thanks. TS.RANGE works fine in the CLI, but not in Grafana. See edit above.

Comment: The explanation of the Legend and Value field in grafana can be found here: https://redisgrafana.github.io/redis-datasource/redis-timeseries/TS-RANGE/

Comment: Added a simple legend and value. Still no dice with data.

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to display a graph (eg, number of people vs time)?  If so, perhaps that TS.INFO is not the right command and you should use something like TS.MRANGE.

Take a look at
https://redislabs.com/blog/how-to-use-the-new-redis-data-source-for-grafana-plug-in/
for some more examples.